# TextView Carousel hide last part of text when scrolling

Tags: android, carousel, android-motionlayout

I'm trying to implement a Carousel with `TextView` but I'm getting a weird glitch. When scrolling the left `TextView` makes the last word of the text disappear, it doesn't matter how long it is, the last word of the text will appear/disappear when scroll and disappear when the scroll is finished. If there is just one word in the TextView the last character dissapear.

Here the example:

[image: Carousel Animation]

**main_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.MainFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
        android:id="@+id/motion_carousel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/carousel_scene"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_title_0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/carousel_names_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="#000"
            android:padding="18dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/text_title_1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Text 0 disappear" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_title_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/carousel_names_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="#000"
            android:padding="18dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/text_title_2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Text 1 disappear" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_title_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000"
            android:padding="18dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Text 2 disappear" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_title_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/carousel_names_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="#000"
            android:padding="18dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text_title_2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Text 3 disappear" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_title_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/carousel_names_horizontal_margin"
            android:background="#000"
            android:padding="18dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text_title_3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Text 4 disappear" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Carousel
            android:id="@+id/carousel_scene_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:carousel_backwardTransition="@+id/backward"
            app:carousel_firstView="@+id/text_title_2"
            app:carousel_forwardTransition="@+id/forward"
            app:carousel_nextState="@+id/next"
            app:carousel_previousState="@+id/previous"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="text_title_0,text_title_1,text_title_2,text_title_3,text_title_4" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**carousel_scene.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    motion:defaultDuration="5000">

    <Transition
        android:id="@+id/forward"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/next"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="100">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragLeft"
            motion:maxAcceleration="20"
            motion:onTouchUp="decelerateAndComplete"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="left" />
    </Transition>

    <Transition
        android:id="@+id/backward"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/previous"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        motion:duration="100">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragRight"
            motion:maxAcceleration="20"
            motion:onTouchUp="decelerateAndComplete"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="right" />

    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/previous">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/text_title_0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/carousel_names_horizontal_margin"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/text_title_1"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/text_title_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/carousel_names_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/carousel_names_horizontal_margin"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/text_title_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/carousel_names_horizontal_margin"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text_title_1"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/text_title_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/carousel_names_horizontal_margin"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/text_title_2"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/text_title_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/carousel_names_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/carousel_names_horizontal_margin"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/text_title_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/carousel_names_horizontal_margin"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text_title_2"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/next">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/text_title_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/carousel_names_horizontal_margin"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/text_title_3"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/text_title_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/carousel_names_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/carousel_names_horizontal_margin"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/text_title_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/carousel_names_horizontal_margin"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text_title_3"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

**MainFragment.kt**

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = MainFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: MainFragmentBinding

    private val nameList = mutableListOf<String>()

    init {

        for (i in 0..7){
            nameList.add("Text ${i} disappear")
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = MainFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.carouselSceneTitle.setAdapter(object : Carousel.Adapter {
            override fun count(): Int {
                return nameList.size
            }

            override fun populate(view: View, index: Int) {
                (view as TextView).apply {
                    text = nameList[index]
                }
            }

            override fun onNewItem(index: Int) {
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised that adding an empty space after the text fixes the problem but it's more a workaround than a proper solution.

```
override fun populate(view: View, index: Int) {
    (view as TextView).apply {
        text = " " + nameList[index] + " "
    }
}
```